# Draw Arabic Text to Canvas for printing

Tags: android, canvas, printing, bitmap, arabic

I am working on a project where I am printing vouchers to a pos printer.  So far I only had to print English so that was fine, however, a new requirement has been added to print arabic.  From research I gather this is all but impossible and the printer manual states that the printer doesn't have arabic character set.

So I'm wondering if it's possible to draw it to canvas correctly so I can create a bitmap.

I have tried this in a previous project but the writing was very small and not formatted in the way the string was.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Regards, 
Gary

Comment: It seems possible, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961636/html5-canvas-filltext-with-right-to-left-string

Comment: @Niddro hi, I failed to mention I was trying this on Android

Comment: give sample code of what you have done, and a snapshot, and which version of android you are testing on.

Comment: I have it printing on POS printer in English, now it's a requirement to print Arabic.  I don't have anything done with it as of yet....Do you mean from the previous project?

Comment: you can use a normal TextView then draw it on your canvas

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242757/how-to-draw-textview-on-canvas-in-android