# How do I get Konva's canvas to go from right to left

Tags: konvajs

I want to display some Hebrew text using Text and TextPath. In plain HTML5 it seems the best way is to set the `dir` attribute on the `canvas` to `rtl` ([HTML5 Canvas fillText with Right-to-Left string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961636/html5-canvas-filltext-with-right-to-left-string/15979861)). How do I do that in Konva?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const canvas = layer.getCanvas()._canvas;

canvas.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');
```

http://jsbin.com/wezusafebi/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks! It works for Text but not for TextPath. Guess I'm missing something

Comment: Yeah. TextPath is drawing each symbol manually. So you have to do adjustment by yourself.