# Multiple colored line of text on canvas

Tags: text, html5-canvas

This is more of a solution than a question. I figured this out and thought others like me might want to know.

I did find "[Can I do by character text color in HTML5 Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665342/can-i-do-by-character-text-color-in-html5-canvas)" when searching but I didn't want to use a "round about way" function.

That led me to gradients e.g. createLinearGradient. And I figured out how to hard block the colors so there was no gradient just two blocks of color. This is what I did:

```
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 300, 0);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "red");
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "red");
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "blue");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "blue");
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
```

This code allows text to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU1Dx.png) and also allows for multiple colors of text on one line of text. Check out this example: [w3school example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FR0P1ZXJB6LD). Hope this helps.

Also, sorry if I'm not supposed to post solutions as questions.

Comment: Indeed you are not supposed to. What you ca do however, is to write a real question and self-answer it. Be careful though that both the question and the answer must stand above our quality-rules, moreover for self-answers, you might want to have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: But actually, this question has already been [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665342/can-i-do-by-character-text-color-in-html5-canvas), so instead of rewriting the same question again, you might want to simply post a new answer there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted as an answer to an other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665342/can-i-do-by-character-text-color-in-html5-canvas)

Comment: Okie dokie. I'll move my answer to the character text color question.